# In which Controller should I write logic for Models that are in a relationship

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, blogs

I am making a blog with users who each have posts. Naturally, I have a UserController, PostController, and a User and Post model.

The User model has a one-to-many relationship with the Post model like so

```
// User Model
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
```

I would like to get all the posts of a specific user by using

```
// UserController or PostController...
$posts = User::find($id)->posts()->get()
```

Should I write this logic in my UserController (because it uses the User model) or should I write the logic in my PostController (because it returns posts)?

Comment: Actually, you just need to create the relationship as you did, and then you can call it whatever you want. Also, if you want the other way around (to know who is the user behind the post), you can create a relationship on your Post model using `belongsTo()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you just need to create the relationship as you did, and then you will be able call it wherever you want, just like as you described, with `User::find($id)->posts()->get()`.

So, if you need to return a user's post on a view, for instance, you can do something like that on your UserController:

```
public function postsView(User $user)
{
    $posts = $user->posts()->get();
    return view('user.posts', compact('posts'));
}
```

Also, if you want the other way around (to know who is the user behind the post), you can create a relationship on your Post model using `belongsTo()`.

```
// Post Model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Model `User` put the relationship.

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post','foreign_key','local_key');
}
```

In your `UserController` or `PostController` get the results by using

```
$posts = User::find($id);
foreach($posts->posts as $post)
{
  echo $post->title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query anywhere in `UserController` or  `PostController`

```
$user = User::with('posts')->whereId($id)->first();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($user->toArray());
exit;
```

You'll get `user` with all `posts`

Answer (score 0):

You can query from both controllers. From where you want to query the relationship depends on where and how you want to fetch data from.

For example, if you are showing posts related to user on a user profile page with other bio data etc then you will call the relationship in UserController.

On other hand, let's say you want to show posts related to an author on a search page then it will be better to have the posts queried via relationship in PostController.

In short, it's a choice based on convenience and optimization to be made.